Is there an edit of The Italian Job (1969) where they have to drive at exactly 10mph?
I recently watched 1969's The Italian Job with my kids.
I had seen it when I was young, and going in I had a very specific recollection that the computer tape at the traffic control centre not only causes traffic chaos in central Turin, but it also sequences the traffic lights to facilitate the Minis' escape - the gimmick being that they had to drive at exactly 10mph for the route to work.
Come this point in the movie... not a sausage.
Lots of driving on footpaths, up & down stairs, through drains and across weirs, the test track atop the Fiat building... and one impressive but inexplicable detour atop the Palavela arena.
But at no point - especially during the initial escape from central Turin - do the traffic lights provide the escape route.
So... Did I watch an edit?  Or am I confusing it with another film?

There's certainly nothing specific about sequenced lights in the transcript.

"they divide the $27 million in gold among the three Minis. They race from the subway to the Los Angeles River and through the city, pursued by Steve's henchmen on motorcycles, with Napster creating a green wave to evade traffic." - thats from the 2003 Italian Job, maybe you've mixed it with that version ?

There is no tape in the control centre.  The lights are disrupted by interference boxes dropped into litter bins by Fred Emney.  You definitely remembered a different film.

The traffic light gimmick is from the newer version. Napster is controlling the lights in real time. Nothing about having to drive at a special speed though.

@Chenmunka - There's a tape machine in the 1969 version; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_O5lEBqnQqg

@Valorum Yes, I know: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26832/18237

That's the problem with (and beauty of) humans brains: they are often wrong/mistaken/subjective/untrustworthy. If you're asking if there exists an alternative version of The Italian Job (1969), that's probably within the scope of the site (but merely based on a vague memory it's not a high quality question, IMO), but asking what film you're confused with is an ID question, which is as of yet still off-topic (and given the sparse context probably opinion-based).

Chenmunka: "There is no tape in the control centre." ... Valorum: "There's a tape machine in the 1969 version." ... Chenmunka: "Yes, I know."

@Chenmunka: The interference boxes disable the surveillance cameras, not the traffic lights.

Then I misremember it too.

@Jeremy - I was too polite to point out that he's literally written an answer about it :-)))

I'd specifically be interested in why a completely weird speed of 16.0934 km/h should do the trick

I've been informed by a family member that we had a book (novelisation) of the film, which apparently included this 10mph element - as well as a completely different ending.

A quote (if you can find one) would really flesh out this answer :-)
